# pygame on OSX Yosemite: unrecognized music format

Tags: python, pygame, sdl

I'm playing around with Pygame on my Mac, running OSX Yosemite.  I can't get it to play an MP3 file using the following code:

```
pygame.mixer.music.load('bg_music.mp3')
pygame.error: Unrecognized music format
```

I'm using Python 2.7.1 and have the following libraries installed:

- sdl (brew): 1.2.15
- sdl_mixer (brew): 1.2.12
- libvorbis (brew): 1.3.4
- pygame: 1.9.2a0

I've searched around and tried all the suggestions [on this thread](https://github.com/justinmeister/Mario-Level-1/issues/5) without success.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can get this thing to work?

Answer (score 4):

Do you have SMPEG library installed? libvorbis is used for .ogg support, .mp3 requires either SMPEG or MAD libraries, as stated in [SDL_mixer manual](http://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/docs/SDL_mixer.html#SEC2).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, thanks the Cynikal's post I was finally able to resolve this. You can ignore step2 if you have already installed pygame. Also change pip3 to pip and remove python3 from the brew install list if you plan to use python27 or something

Step 1:
Install all Pygame deps for Mac with Brew (if you don't have brew, look up how to install first)

```
brew install python3 hg sdl sdl_image sdl_ttf portmidi smpeg
```

Step 2:
Install PyGame

```
pip3 install hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

Step 3:
Download sdl-mixer source code from: https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release-1.2.html

Untar the tar.gz file with tar zxvf:

```
tar zxvf SDL_mixer-1.2.12.tar.gz
cd SDL_mixer-1.2.12
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Step 4:
Run your pygame code and see if it fixes your dependency issue

I hope this helps others who come to this with the same issue I had on OS X Yosemite

Comment: I tried this with no help -still getting pygame.error: Unrecognized music format

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was using python 2 instead of `python3`

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same problem its because of **pygame version 1.9.5** 
my problem was sloved when I installed **1.9.6 version**
try this command it really worked:

```
python -m pip install pygame==1.9.6.rc1 --user --pre
```